# Drupal Entity API and Views bulk operations - "Modify entity values" action provides empty form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-entities

I created new entity, some sample entities and views using VBO table. "Delete" VBO action works well, but "Modify entity values" provides an empty form with "Next" button and "Cancel" link only. If I submit this form Drupal shows me an error msg: "You must select at least one value to modify."
I tried to solve an issue with hook_entity_property_info(), but it doesn't help.